# Cpp debug assertion error on function return

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a Boost websocket service that streams data using the google protobuf format. I've implemented a pretty simple library with a .h and a .cpp file but I'm getting the following error when exiting connect() from cryptowatch_API.cpp (checked with brakepoints).

Debug Assertion Failed!

File: debug_heap.cpp
Line: 908
Expression: is_block_type_valid(header -> _block_use)

The weirdest thing is that the code runs until the end without problems once every while... Has anybody got any idea what might go wrong here? My files are posted below and I'm using VS2019. Any help would be really appreciated! I've been struggling with this for quite some time...

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "public/stream/stream.pb.h"
#include "cryptowatch_API.h"

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;       // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
int main()
{
GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;


const char* API_key = "INSERT_API_KEY";
Cryptowatch_API cryptowatch_API(API_key);

ProtobufStream::AuthenticationResult::Status auth_status;
auth_status = cryptowatch_API.connect();
/*
if (auth_status == ProtobufStream::AuthenticationResult::AUTHENTICATED) {
    std::cout << "Authentication successful" << std::endl;
}
else {
    //std::cout << "Authentication failed: " << auth_status << std::endl;
}
*/
cryptowatch_API.disconnect();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

The .h file:

```
// cryptowatch_API.h

#ifndef Cryptowatch_API_H // include guard
#define Cryptowatch_API_H

class Cryptowatch_API
{
private:
    const char* API_key;
    boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>>* ws;
public:
    Cryptowatch_API(const char*);
    ProtobufStream::AuthenticationResult::Status connect();
    void disconnect();
};

#endif Cryptowatch_API_H
```

The .cpp file:

```
// cryptowatch_API.cpp
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "public/stream/stream.pb.h"
#include "cryptowatch_API.h"

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;       // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

Cryptowatch_API::Cryptowatch_API(const char* API_key) {
    Cryptowatch_API::API_key = API_key;
}

void Cryptowatch_API::disconnect() {
    //ws->close(websocket::close_code::normal);
}

//Will return TRUE when connect was successful, FALSE when unsuccessful
ProtobufStream::AuthenticationResult::Status Cryptowatch_API::connect() {
    // Check command line arguments.
    auto const host = "stream.cryptowat.ch";
    auto const port = "443";

    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    net::io_context ioc;

    // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
    ssl::context ctx{ ssl::context::tlsv12_client };

    // This holds the root certificate used for verification
    //load_root_certificates(ctx);

    // These objects perform our I/O
    tcp::resolver resolver{ ioc };
    websocket::stream<beast::ssl_stream<tcp::socket>> webs{ ioc, ctx };
    //Dereference the websocket object to store it in Cryptowatch_API
    ws = &webs;

    // Look up the domain name
    auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);

    // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
    net::connect(ws->next_layer().next_layer(), results.begin(), results.end());

    // Perform the SSL handshake
    ws->next_layer().handshake(ssl::stream_base::client);

    // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
    ws->set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
        [](websocket::request_type& req)
        {
            req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                " websocket-client-coro");
        }));

    // Perform the websocket handshake
    std::string connect_url_addition = "/connect?format=binary&apikey=";
    connect_url_addition.append(API_key);
    ws->handshake(host, connect_url_addition);

    // This buffer will hold the incoming message
    beast::flat_buffer buffer;

    ProtobufStream::StreamMessage streamMessage;
    //streamMessage.InitAsDefaultInstance();
    while (streamMessage.has_authenticationresult() == FALSE) {
        buffer.clear();
        if (ws->read(buffer) > 0) {
            //Parse streamMessage from the websocket input message
            streamMessage.ParseFromArray(static_cast<char const*>(buffer.data().data()), buffer.data().size());
        }

    }
    ProtobufStream::AuthenticationResult::Status authenticated;
    authenticated = streamMessage.authenticationresult().status();

    return authenticated;
}
```

Comment: `//Dereference the websocket object to store it in Cryptowatch_API` -- You're storing the address of a local variable.  Once that function returns, that address has gone up in a puff of smoke.

Comment: While this was of course an error that had to be fixed as well (thanks for pointing me to it!) it was actually the protobuf library that was messing things up.

streamMessage.ParseFromArray(static_cast<char const*>(buffer.data().data()), buffer.data().size()); gave errors when it was destructed when buffer.data().size() was only 1.